# FireMonkey: Reading file in OS X from Samba

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, samba

I'm writing a small FireMonkey-App with Embarcadero Delphi XE5 for OS X (testing in 10.9 on my iMac) to read a text file from a Samba "drive" which is connected to my Win7 machine. The file is accessible by double clicking it but TStringList doesn't seem to be able to load it. I do not get any error message (not even an exception). After calling LoadFromFile() the *Text* attribute is empty.

I tried TStringList, TStringStream (with *DataString* property), TFileStream and FileOpen()/FileRead()/FileClose(). The first two seems to be empty after loading. TFileStream doesn't read data or reads garbage (maybe I just wrote it wrong). However FileOpen()/FileRead() works fine. Is it possible to use TStringList in FireMonkey applications or is this some kind of limitation for multi-platform applications?

PS: I tried to mount my shared folder as Guest and as the administrator user of the Win7 machine.

Here is the example code I used to test it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl: TStringList;
  ss: TStringStream;
  fs: TFileStream;
  b: array[0..20480] of char;
  sFile: String;

  FileHandle : Integer;
  iFileLength: Integer;
  Buffer: PAnsiChar;
  iBytesRead: Integer;
begin
  sFile := '/Volumes/freigabe/aida64_2013-12-13_18-50-09_log.csv';

  sl := TStringList.Create();
  sl.LoadFromFile(sFile);
  ShowMessage(sl.Text);  // Empty

  ss := TStringStream.Create();
  ss.LoadFromFile(sFile);
  ShowMessage(ss.DataString);  // Empty

  fs := TFileStream.Create(sFile, fmOpenRead);
  fs.Read(b, fs.Size);
  ShowMessage(AnsiString(b));  // Garbage data - I think I do it wrong with Read() above...

  // Example from documentation
  FileHandle := SysUtils.FileOpen(sFile, fmOpenRead);
  if FileHandle > 0 then
    begin
      try
        iFileLength := SysUtils.FileSeek(FileHandle,0,2);
        FileSeek(FileHandle, 0, 0);
        Buffer := PAnsiChar(System.AllocMem(iFileLength + 1));
        iBytesRead := SysUtils.FileRead(FileHandle, Buffer^, iFileLength);
      finally
        FreeMem(Buffer);

      ShowMessage(Buffer);  // OK!
      end;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage('Error');


  sl.Free;
  ss.Free;
  fs.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Your use of the "example from documentation" has a serious error you introduced: `finally FreeMem(Buffer); ShowMessage(Buffer);` is not `// OK!`. Your `ShowMessage` should absolutely come **before** you free the memory with `FreeMem`; it's only working because nothing has been done between those two lines of code, but you're accessing memory you've just freed. (The `ShowMessage` should actually happen in the last line before the `finally` statement.)

Comment: Can you load the file in a text editor on your Mac?

Comment: Hello, Do you check Encoding format?

Comment: @Ken White: The question was not related to this bug and so is irrelevant.

Comment: @Yaroslav Brovin: Thank you. This was the problem. I had to accept DA's response as accepted answer (since you wrote a comment only) but you gave the correct anser first.

Comment: No, it's not *irrelevant*. It is totally relevant, because accessing the contents of memory after it's been freed is a serious mistake that can cause undefined behavior and hard to track down problems in other areas of the code. I didn't say it was the cause of *this problem* - I merely pointed out that you'd introduced a serious bug that could cause other problems. If I'd thought it was the cause of the problem here, I would have posted an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same issue with `LoadFromFile` also with local files. The Text attribute was empty all the time.
It worked after I called the method with the Encoding parameter:

```
htmlFile := TStringList.Create;    
htmlFile.LoadFromFile(sourceFile, TEncoding.ASCII);
```

Hopefully this will help you too.

Andy

Comment: Thank you! This was the reason.